# Group by using a function result SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, user-defined-functions

How to group the entire SQL query using scalar valued function result.

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,udf_IsNumaric_Get(Param1,Param2)
FROM Table1
WHERE Col1 LIKE '%123%'
GROUP BY --Function result
ORDER BY --Function result
```

OR

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2) AS Count
FROM Table1
WHERE Col1 LIKE '%123%'
GROUP BY --Count
ORDER BY --Count
```

Is it possible to group the entire SQL query by using the output of the `udf_IsNumaric_Get` scalar valued function or using the `SELECT` statement in the 2nd example..

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server, MySQL?

Comment: Your second query does not make sense to me.  Why would you want to group by a single constant number?  To the question suggested in your title, I would expect it to be possible to group by a UDF no less than by an in-built function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using a subquery:

```
SELECT t.Col1,t.Col2,t.Count FROM
  (SELECT Col1,Col2,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2) AS Count
   FROM Table1
   WHERE Col1 LIKE '%123%') as t
   GROUP BY Count
   ORDER BY Count
```